# Map a SMB-drive outside of the LAN

Tags: router, nas, lan, smb, wan

Is it possible to map a network drive in Windows 7 connecting to a NAS on a another local network (behind a firewall)?

Here's my setup (so far):
- Linksys wireless router connected to the internet
- Buffalo LinkStation Live connected to a LAN-port on the router

From outside the LAN I can get in contact with a shared folder on the LinkStation (via ftp or webaccess).
It's also possible on the LinkStation to mark a folder "Windows", which means it can be accessed using SMB.
If I do so, I'm able to map the drive (using "net use") within the LAN.

But what about from outside? Is it even possible to map a SMB drive that situated on another local network?

I've opened port 445 and 135-139 in the router and forwards traffic to the LinkStation.

What do I do from here?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You **don't** want to transport plain SMB over the public Internet. It is not encrypted!
Look if your Linksys router supports VPN. (Virtual Private Networks). Configure VPN on your router. Install a client on your outside PC and connect to the VPN. As a result you are like physically connected to your LAN and are able to access your shares.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to setup a VPN on my router (LinkSys WRT54GC). I think not...

It has a "VPN passthrough"-tab, with the following settings:
IPSec Passthrough
L2TP Passthrough
PPTP Passthrough
- All of them enabled.

Comment: Perhaps your NAS-box can provide VPN. Or you can setup a VPN server on one of your LAN computers.
Or perhaps you can install an alternate firmware on your router.

Comment: The WRT54GC cannot be upgraded with alternate firmware, and I cannot find any way to do it on the NAS. So I think I'll have to set up a VPN server on my network to route the trafic through. Thanks for helping!